# How to get the value of a field in jtable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

I'm new to jtable and trying to figure out how can I get the selected value of a field (Types, dropdown); and based on this value, I need to make a call to a Java class and get the value for field 2 (Price, input type).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var selectedValue = null;
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
        title : 'Students List',
        actions : {
            listAction : 'Controller?action=list',
            createAction : 'Controller?action=create',
            updateAction: function(postData) {
            var values = [];
            console.log("updating from custom function...");
            return $.Deferred(function($dfd) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: './Controller?action=update',
                    type: 'POST',
  `enter code here`                  dataType: 'json',
                    data: postData,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(entryindex, entry) {
                          values.push(entry['typeId']);  
                        });
                        alert(values);
                        $dfd.resolve(data);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $dfd.reject();
                    }
                });
            });
        },
    deleteAction : 'Controller?action=delete'

        },
        fields : {
            studentId : {
                title : 'Student Id',  
                width : '30%',
                key : true,
                list : true,
                edit : false,
                create : true
            },
            name : {
                title : 'Name',
                width : '30%',
                edit : true
            },

            emailId : {
                title : 'Email',
                width : '20%',
                edit : true
            },
            typeId : {
                title : 'types',
                width : '20%',
                edit : true,
                listClass:'genderClass',
                options: { 'S':'Select','D': 'Dynamic', 'F': 'Fixed', 'C':'Customize' }
            },
            priceId : {
                title : 'Price',
                width : '20%',
                edit : true
            }

        }

 });

});
```

Based on the selection of 'TypeId', I need to populate the value of the `Price`. I tried putting in some logic in the 'updateAction', but no luck.

Comment: I've deleted your [tag:java] tag, and if I'm wrong, please let me know. Please understand that Java and Javascript are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: I've also refined the tag selection.